# Tomcat Catalina log file customization

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to change my catalina.logs file location from default place to the desired state. I edited my logging.properties file like below.

```
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
```

to:

```
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/home/sys2logs
```

After updating the file, I have restarted my tomcat and when I am checking my home directory /home/sys2logs not exist, can you please someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

i can able to achieve above scenario, after updating like below

'''
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = /home/sys2logs
'''